# Ember TextField valueBinding to controller issue

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember.js-view, ember-controllers

I am using the Twitter typeahead.js plugin. So to use it I am extend Ember's TextField. The plugin all works fine. Now I just want to make the value accessible inside the controller.

When I use the value binding inside the view class, it works fine. Here is the [bin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nohuj/3/edit). Here the value gets set initially and updates later. To test the text view type 'aaa'.

```
App.TypeAhead = Ember.TextField.extend({      
  classNames: ['cmp-typeahead'],    
  attributeBindings: ['id','value'],    
  valueBinding: 'targetObject.airportCode',
  ....
});
```

But when I try to set the value binding via the template, it doesn't seem to work. Here is the [bin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nohuj/2/edit). To test the text view type 'aaa'.

```
{{view App.TypeAhead data=airports valueBinding="view.targetObject.airportCode" 
       id="fromAirportCode"}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the view helper will keep the current controller, it's as simple as:

```
{{view App.TypeAhead data=airports valueBinding="airportCode" 
   id="fromAirportCode"}}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ciwiv/1/edit

Comment: Thanks this is working. But can I get the airportCode value directly in the view like this.get('airportCode'). Right now I need to use this.get('targetObject.airportCode'); My thought is if the view helper gets the controller, the class would also get it.